# Differences between moments of char pointer assignment

Tags: c, c-strings

Today I was told, that this code:

```
int main(){
 char *a;
 a = "foobar";
 /* a used later to strcpy */
 return 0;
}
```

Is bad, and may lead to problems and errors.
However, my code worked without any problems, and I don't understand, what is the difference between this, and

```
int main(){
 char *a = "foobar";
 /* a used later to strcpy */
 return 0;
}
```

Which was described to me as the "correct" way.
Could someone describe, why these two codes are different?
And, if the first one may be problematic, show an example of this?

Comment: Why do you think the first one is worse than the second? They are pretty much equally bad as the pointers aren't const.

Comment: How was `a` in `strcpy()` used?

Comment: Of course not as destination ;)

Comment: I didn't use const, because I was writing code in C older than ANSI C, there was no `const` keyword yet.

Answer (score 3):

Functionally, they are the same.

In the former snippet, `a` is assigned to a string literal; in the latter, `a` is initialized with a string literal.
In both cases, `a` points to string literal (which can't be modified).

There's no reason to consider one as more correct than the other. I'd prefer the latter - but that's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Both snippets are equally bad, because both end in a non const pointer pointing to const data. If the non const pointer is used to (try to) change the data, you will get Undefined Behaviour: everything can happen from *it works* to *program crashes* including *modifying instruction is ignored*.

The correct way is to either use a const pointer or to initialize a non const array.

```
const char *a = "foobar";
```

or

```
char a[] = "foobar";
```

But beware, in latter case you have a true array not a pointer, so you could also do if you really need pointer semantics:

```
char _a[] = "foobar";
char *a = _a;
```

Comment: I didn't use `const` keyword, because I wrote this code in plain C, const appeared in C89, on university they teach us even older standard, I just copied my code from there.

Comment: @Kaznov My answer indeed assumed a decently recent C version :-). I'm old enough to remember original K&R C... In those old versions, string litteral were modifiable and your code would be correct. But you will have to quickly change those coding practice if you have to product *real* code...

Answer (score 1):

There are some places that have coding standards, for instance to help with static code analysis by tools like Coverity.

A coding practice rule that I have seen several places is that variables should always be declared initialized to simplify things to make analysis easier.

You second snippet hews more closely to that rule than the first, as its impossible to insert new code where `a` could be used uninitialized.

That's a positive benefit when it comes to code maintenance.